# Build report from Excel file with multiple tabs?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010

A friend saves the data about her students into an Excel file with multiple tabs (one per year, since the list of students changes every year.)

Because there are too many columns to fit in a report, she'd like to display them in individual tables, one per trimester.

Here's a mock-up built with LibreOffice:
[image]
Problem is, Word can only work with a single tab from Excel, so its mail merge feature won't do.

Before telling her that she must find someone able to build a database application with some reporting add-on, does someone know of a work-around?

---

Edit: There could be a better way, but a work-around is to put all the data in one worksheet where each trimester should include the year (eg. T1-2012), and each section in the Word mail merge document should include some "If/then" block to avoid printing sections that are irrelevant for a given student.

Comment: What about linking the mailshot data onto an extra tab?

Comment: What's "mailshot data"?

Comment: Sorry, "mail merge".

Comment: Have you looked at [Pivot Tables/Reports](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx) or [Dashboards](http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-dashboards/)?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I found a work-around and edited the question accordingly.